# Javascript if else loop not working

Tags: javascript

I am currently working on a interactive timeline page generated all in js, but this loop is making the page not work

```js
if (i = 0) {
        console.log('magic');
} else if (i = 1) {
        console.log('magic');
} else if (i = 2 ) {
        console.log('magic');
} else if (i = 3) {
        console.log('magic');
} else if (i = 4) {
        console.log('magic');
} else if (i = 5) {
        console.log('magic');
} else if (i = 6) {
        console.log('magic');
} else if (i = 7) {
        console.log('magic');
} else {
        console.log('magic');
}
```

Comment: it seems to be working for me :) what is your desired result?

Comment: use === you are using assignment

Comment: title says Java, tag says javascript, question days js... wow

Comment: for the page to load @JeffPuckettII it isn't even loading even though it was loading near instantly before I put the loop in (There was previous js in the doc it is in)

Answer (score 1):

Hum... you are using `=` you are assigning `i` value as `0` , so replace `=` for `==`

And remove all `{ }` from the `else if` and `else` statements , because you have only one line of code inside them.

Comment: only remove the `{ }` **if** there's only one line of code. I suspect there's only one line in this example for simplicity

Comment: @JeffPuckettII , yes, but if not, it's better talk than pass in blank